# Nginx redirect without using a port

Tags: linux, nginx, ssl, proxy, redirect

I am using a nginx to redirect from several http services with IP:PORT to a https domain. Now I need the nginx to redirect only:

**http://IP to https://DOMAIN** and open it in Browser with:
**https://DOMAIN:PORT** because I have several Ports on the Server and want evrything in the same ssl domain. Is this possible? All my tests I made failed so far...

```
###
### PROXY CONFIG FOR bot*******.*****.de
###

    server {
    server_name bot*******.*****.de; # managed by Certbot
        root         /usr/share/nginx/default;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

     port_in_redirect off;

        location / {
          proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
          proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
          proxy_pass          http://###.####.###.####;
          proxy_read_timeout  90;
          proxy_redirect      http://###.####.###.#### https://bot*******.*****.de;
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/bot*******.*****.dee/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/bot*******.*****.de/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

    server {
    if ($host = bot*******.*****.de) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen       80 ;
        listen       [::]:80 ;
    server_name bot*******.*****.de;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}

## ENDE BOTCONF
```

Comment: The configuration file seems unrelated to your question as it uses the standard `https` port. Please expand your question with examples using the non-standard ports you are attempting to implement.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you please provide examples?

Comment: okey, i try to explain: i like to redirect an http service like http ://192.168.1.2 to https ://example.org
on my 192.168.1.2 are running services on may ports. i dont want a direct for evry single service because the ports a dynmic. because of that i thought i can redirect only the http ://IP to https://domain and open then in my browser the desired service with https ://domain:port - thats the solution i need. in my example config i dont use a port, but if i open a https ://domain:port i get a 404 from nginx.